# Replicating rows in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
N  numbers
n1 1,2,3
n2 4,6,2
n4 2,5
....


frequency=[0.45,   0.5,  0.05]
Activ =   [  1,      2,     3]

df = shuffle(df)[:20] 

Activs=np.random.choice(Activ , len(df), p=frequency)
df['index']=pd.Series(Activs.tolist())

df_new = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values,df.index)]
```

I want to get a data frame of the type of:

```
df_new:
N  numbers index
n1 1,2,3     3
n1 1,2,3     3
n2 4,6,2     2
n2 4,6,2     2
n2 4,6,2     2
n1 1,2,3     1  
n4 2,5       2
  ....
```

I get an error - in my frame  a date value in colum index numbers and NaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think column `index` is not necessary, for [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) is possible use `array` `Activs`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': ['1,2,3', '4,6,2', '2,5'], 'N': ['n1', 'n2', 'n4']})
print (df)
    N numbers
0  n1   1,2,3
1  n2   4,6,2
2  n4     2,5

frequency=[0.45,   0.5,  0.05]
Activ =   [  1,      2,     3]

df = df[:20] 

#for testing
np.random.seed(100)
Activs=np.random.choice(Activ , len(df.index), p=frequency)
print (Activs)
[2 1 1]

df_new = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index,Activs)]
print (df_new)
    N numbers
0  n1   1,2,3
0  n1   1,2,3
1  n2   4,6,2
2  n4     2,5
```

But if need new column from `Activs`, better is dont use name `index` if not really necessary - e.g. name is `val`:

```
np.random.seed(100)
Activs=np.random.choice(Activ , len(df.index), p=frequency)
print (Activs)
[2 1 1]
df['val'] = Activs

df_new = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index,Activs)]
print (df_new)
    N numbers  val
0  n1   1,2,3    2
0  n1   1,2,3    2
1  n2   4,6,2    1
2  n4     2,5    1
```